# На каком графике из 8 было нажатие

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Рисую в стандартном Chart C# графики 8 - ми функций. Необходимо узнать на каком графике было нажатие. У каждого графика есть маркер точки. вот мне и нужно узнать на каком маркере было нажатие. X - порядковый номер точки, Y - данные. Ось Y логарифмическая. поэтому метод

```
        chGrafik.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
```

не работает. Настройка маркера:

```
        chGrafik.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;  // при true отображает значение точки в виде метки
        chGrafik.Series[0].MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle; // стиль маркера точки данных
        chGrafik.Series[0].MarkerSize = 9;
        chGrafik.Series[0].MarkerColor = chGrafik.Series[0].Color;                    //цвет точки маркера
        chGrafik.Series[0].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8f, FontStyle.Bold);     //настройка шрифта маркера
```

Comment: При евенте передается два значения в функцию, object - ваш вариант и eventargs - параметры. Вам остаётся явно преобразовать `object в chart: Chart ch = object as Chart;`

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел сам.

```
private void chGrafik_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hit = chGrafik.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (hit.Series != null)
            {
            String Txt = hit.Series.Name;

            switch (Txt)
            {
                case "Series1":
                    valSeries = 1;
                    break;
                case "Series2":
                    valSeries = 2;
                    posClick = 
                    break;
                case "Series3":
                    valSeries = 3;
                    break;
                case "Series4":
                    valSeries = 4;
                    break;
                case "Series5":
                    valSeries = 5;
                    break;
                case "Series6":
                    valSeries = 6;
                    break;
                case "Series7":
                    valSeries = 7;
                    break;
                case "Series8":
                    valSeries = 8;
                    break;
            }
     }
```